# JS and PHP value passing issue

Tags: javascript, php

```
<?php
for ($i=1; $i <10 ; $i++) {
$A='A'.$i; 
echo "<button onclick='selectSeat(id)' id='$A'>".$A."</button>";
}?>

<script type="text/javascript">
function selectSeat (id)
{
    alert ("Button pressed ".id);
}
</script>
```

above is my seating map.... i want to check if if seat is reserved or not in DB through php but i don't know how to get it done through java script. i'm using java script to prompt user in if seat is reserved or not.

Comment: You'll have to make an AJAX call to find out as the seat may have been booked by the time the button's clicked.

Comment: can you provide me some link ? im totaly new to this stuff

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's just a typo, but you are using the wrong operator to concatenate strings in javastring:

```
alert ("Button pressed ".id);
```

Should be

```
alert ("Button pressed "+id);
```

Comment: It worked .. thank you so much.. but how do i check these values db?

Comment: if user selects A1 .. to check if its reserved or not?

Comment: @Rizwan To do this, I'd recomend using AJAX to call another PHP file to check in your DB. If you want to learn more about AJAX requests, [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp) is a simple tutorial.

Comment: <?php
      for ($i=1; $i <10 ; $i++) {
$Seat='A'.$i; 

    echo "<button onclick='selectSeat(id)' id='$Seat'>".$Seat."</button>";
    
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function selectSeat (id)
    {
        var Seat= $('#id');
        alert ("Button pressed "+Seat);
    }
</script

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a hidden input field using PHP with the value you want to send to javascript. Then you can get the value with javascript (either vanilla or jQuery) using $('#hidden-field').val() (for example).